# How do you pull up the java console in OpenSUSE or Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, applet, jconsole

I'm working on a java applet, and I was wondering where the heck System.out was going in Ubuntu/OpenSUSE. In windows, I just pull up jconsole, but I've not found this in Ubuntu/OpenSUSE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the command **jcontrol**. On the **Advanced** tab expand **Java console** and select **Show console**. Restart Firefox and the console should open the next time you open a Java applet in the browser.

Comment: This requires a host and port (sudo apt-get install julius). jcontrol localhost says connection refused.

Comment: jcontrol does neither require a host nor a port. It's a simple UI application. Do you have a Xserver running? Sounds like it cannot connect to the Xserver. Can you run xclock?

Comment: And what's 'julius'? jcontrol is part of the Sun JRE/JDK.

Comment: Is jcontrol just not on the path, then? Yick.

Comment: Ah, I see. jcontrol in ubuntu pulls up misleading information. I needed to setup the jdk on my test machines.

Comment: Well, on my Ubuntu intrepid it's on the path. There is a symlink in /usr/bin/jcontrol. What does 'locate jcontrol' or 'which jcontrol' say? jcontrol is part of sun-java6-bin. Do you have this package installed?

Comment: I installed sun-java6-jdk and I was good to go. If you type "jcontrol" without the jdk installed, you're directed to the julius package.

Comment: there is no jcontrol in openjdk :(

Answer (score 8):

Also, you can run firefox from the terminal to see jconsole output. Jconsole output goes to firefox's standard out.

Comment: Unlike the `jcontrol` solution, this works with OpenJDK as well. Thanks!